# How to output a list of arguments passed to a VBScript script?

Tags: vbscript

I have the following VBScript code:

```
Dim returnVal
returnVal = "You did not pass me 4 arguments"

args = WScript.Arguments.Count

If args = 4 Then
    returnVal = "The arguements you passed me are " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & "  "  & WScript.Arguments.Item(1) & "  "  & WScript.Arguments.Item(2) & "  "  & WScript.Arguments.Item(3) 
end if
```

All I want is the ability to print "returnVal" so that if I typed:

```
test.vbs 1 2 3 4
```

It would return:

```
The arguments you passed me are 1 2 3 4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To output **to the command console window** you can do this using:

```
WScript.Echo returnVal
```

or

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine returnVal
```

But you must use the ***CScript*** host for this to work, for example:

```
cscript.exe myscript.vbs
```

WScript is the GUI host and so has no knowledge of the standard input/output/error/aux streams. Trying to do `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine` will result in the following error dialogue:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: d:\myscript.vbs
Line:   12
Char:   1
Error:  The handle is invalid. 
Code:   80070006
Source:     (null)

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

In a CScript.exe script you can still pop up GUI message dialogues using:

```
Msgbox "Hello World!"
```

Using `WScript.Echo` in a WScript host will display the message in a popup dialogue instead of printing to the command line window.

For more information see:

> [Write Method (Windows Script Host)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5wwy2xet%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For more information on the differences between WScript and CScript and how to switch between them:

> [Sesame Script Stop and Go (MS TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176996.aspx)
>
> *The difference between Cscript and Wscript is that Cscript is the
>   command-line version of the script host and Wscript is the graphical
>   version. This difference isn’t really noticeable unless your script
>   uses the Wscript.Echo command.*

Comment: Dang - 3 secs ... and you included cscript usage.

Comment: For my sins, I worked in a bank and used to look after a 30000 line build system written entirely in vbscript. This experience is burned irreversibly into my noggin :)

Comment: I did not figure it was a hard problem but I am new to scripting. Thanks man :)

Comment: @Kev: +1 for this excellent summary of w/cscript output. May I ask you to take out the misleading 'pass me per value' () from your example sub calls, however?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not after the Message Box suggested by @heximal, you should use StdOut:

```
WScript.StdOut.Write(returnVal)
```

**Important:** This requires **CScript** to be the host executable.

To [change the default script host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245254/en-us), use

```
cscript //h:cscript //s
```